# Master socket fault, which wires go where?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection

Currently I have an OpenReach master socket which has some form of adapter plugged into it which takes a cable to the modem router. Underneath a wire coming in from the house which I assume supplies the internet.

I intermittently receive internet depending on whether the cables stay in position. Is it something I can fix myself, if so what adapters etc… am I looking for?

Below is an image that better illustrates my issue:

[image]

Comment: You will have to at least document the adapter for us.

Comment: Openreach (or your landline provider) should be able to replace the socket for you for free. The phone socket is technically the property of Openreach, everything from the exchange to the socket is their responsibility. I would not recommend attempting to fix this yourself.